# one predictive methods

Tags: predictive-modeling, prediction, machine-learning-model

Is there any algorithm/method/system/application that combine all predictive methods into one?

so for users instead of deciding which method they should use, is there any platform that you just feed the data and it gives you the predictions without the decide which method of predictive analysis you want to use?

Comment: Do you mean that you want some sort of method which automatically decides which algorithm to use for a given data set and its variables? If so, then no. Unless you can guarantee that only specific types of data sets will be used and assign specific algorithms for each one.

Comment: You might want to look at the *ensemble method*, which combines multiple predictors to improve performance. But that does not possibly include *all* predictive methods.

Comment: @user12075 May you please give me more info about these ensemble methods?

Comment: I think you are looking for auto ML tools like Datarobot or H20 driverless, but this would be more of a commercial software discussion